# POST request returning [Object, object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, post

I am trying to send a POST request (using postman) to create an entry in my PostgreSQL database. However, currently my POST request is returning [object, Object], and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the code to handle the request.

```
//enable the router
app.use('/', router);

//Create 
router.post('/api/v1/todos', (req, res, next) => {
  const results = [];
  console.log("Congrats you hit the create function!!");

  //grab data from http-request, 'complete' is from a boolean value in the database
  const data = {text: req.query.text, complete: false };

  //give error if not recieving a request 
  if(!req.query.text) res.send(400, "The Request data is: " + req.query);

  //get a prostgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    //handle connection errors
    if (err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }

    //SQL Query -> Insert Data
    client.query('INSERT INTO items(text, complete) values($1,$2)', 
    [data.text, data.complete]);

    //SQL Query -> Select Data
    const query = client.query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC");

    //Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });

    //After all data is returned, close connection and return the results
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
      //return res.json(data);
    });
  });
});
```

And here is my POST
[image: POST image]

Why is my data returning objects? What can I do in order to resolve this?

[Here is my full code](http://pastebin.com/zDz9YF9Q).

Comment: You are converting an object to a string here: `res.send(400, "The Request data is: " + req.query);`. The default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. Try it yourself by pasting the following into your browser's console: `("Object string representation:" + {})`.

Comment: *"What can I do in order to resolve this?"* Just don't do it? What other behavior do you want? I'm nor really sure what kind of answer/solution your are looking for.

Comment: @FelixKling this tells me what I wanted to know, thanks! In any case, nothing is posting to my database, so I need to figure out why now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating a string with an object, this will convert the object to a string in a form of `[object Object]`.

Here's your problem: `if(!req.query.text) res.send(400, "The Request data is: " + req.query);`

`req.query` is an object (you're just checking it the text property exists) and you're concatenating a string to that object.